# Inside a state of ionic1, how to pass $stateParams to views?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

For example, there is a state, which controls 2 views:

www/index.html

```
<html>
  .
  .
  .
  <body ng-app='starter' ng-controller="MainCtrl"><p>
    <ui-view name="redView" style="color:red;"></ui-view>
    <ui-view name="greenView" style="color:green;"></ui-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

www/js/app.js

```
angular.module('starter',['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('contacts',{
      'views':{
        'redView':{
          template:'<p>Red View</p>',
          controller:function($scope,$stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams.redString);
          }
        },
        'greenView':{
          template:'<p>Green View</p>',
          controller:function($scope,$stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams.greenString);
          }
        }
      }
    });
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
  $state.go('contacts',{redString:'abc',greenString:'def'});
});
```

I passed parameter "redString" and "greenString" to the state 'contacts', but

```
console.log($stateParams.redString);
```

and

```
console.log($stateParams.greenString);
```

prints undefined. What am I doing wrong? How to let

```
console.log($stateParams.redString);
```

prints 'abc' successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare a default value for the parameters in the state object

```
.state('contacts',{
  'views':{
    'redView':{
      template:'<p>Red View</p>',
      controller:function($scope,$stateParams){
      console.log($stateParams.redString);
     }
   },
  'greenView':{
     template:'<p>Green View</p>',
     controller:function($scope,$stateParams){
     console.log($stateParams.greenString);
     }
   },
   params: {
     //here
     redString: null,
     greenString: null
   }
 })



.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
  $state.go('contacts',{redString:'abc',greenString:'def'});
});
```